# jquery modal window

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Is there a jquery modal window which on on click on the background doesnt closeup.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at

**[jQuery Ui dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal)**

Answer (score 0):

**[BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos)**

Comment: Cool demos,but what about the code plugin informations?which plugin have you used for this